# load json file as a variable with an input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am sure my question has already been answered but none of the answers helped me. Sorry for that.

The following script allows me to display json's name, size, lastModifiedDate but I cannot manage to have the content of the loaded json.

E.g. var json = ...

What I want to do is to use the json attributes and values to plot some graphs, but I don't know how to do it..

Any idea?

I am trying to load a json file as a variable by using an input form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look here : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: and read this documentation : https://plot.ly/javascript/

Comment: would need to use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to get contents of file if you are trying to read it locally. Note that it is only supported in modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contents of the file you choose with this code, using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

```
var json = null;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(f, "UTF-8");
reader.onload = function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.result)
  try{
    json = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);
  }
  catch(e){
    alert('there was an error: ' + e);
  }
}
```

Putting it all together

```
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      var json = null;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(f, "UTF-8");
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.result)
        try{
          json = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);
        }
        catch(e){
          alert('there was an error: ' + e);
        }
      }
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileReader. This example creates the json string as an Object, then goes over each property to display them in a list.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
<output id="details"></output>
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.readAsText(f);


            r.onload = function (e) {
                var json = e.target.result;
                var jObject = JSON.parse(json);
                var jObjectPropertyHtml = '<ul>';
                for (var propertyName in jObject) {
                    if (jObject.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
                        var propertyHtml = '<li>' + propertyName + ':' + jObject[propertyName] + '</li>';
                        jObjectPropertyHtml += propertyHtml;
                    }
                }
                jObjectPropertyHtml += '</ul>';
                var html = document.getElementById('details').innerHTML + jObjectPropertyHtml;
                document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = html;
            }

            output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                '</li>');


        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```